# What is the difference between "compile" and "build"?

Tags: build, compilation

What is the difference between "compile" and "build"?
Think it is similar, but can't understand what's the subtle difference

Comment: If this question is about a specific environment, please indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the language and build process, building may do more than just compiling (such as creating jar files) or not include compilation at all (such as concatenating and compressing Javascript files).